# Microsoft Speech Platform speech to text

Tags: c#, microsoft-speech-platform

I'd like to write the speech a user says to text. Can I do this with the Microsoft Speech Platform? Perhaps I'm just misunderstanding how it's supposed to work and what its intended use case is.

I've got this console application now:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Choices words = new Choices();
            words.Add(new string[] { "test", "hello" ,"blah"});
            GrammarBuilder gb = new GrammarBuilder();
            gb.Append(words);
            Grammar g = new Grammar(gb);

            SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
            sre.LoadGrammar(g);
            sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

            //add listeners

            sre.Recognize();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

And it only seems to output the words that I specify in `Choices`.

Would I have to add an entire dictionary of words if I wanted to match (most) of what a user will say?

Furthermore it stops right after it matches a single word. What if I wanted to capture entire sentences?

I'm looking for solutions for A) Capturing a wide array of words, and B) capturing more than one word at once.

### Edit:

I found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a#torecognizeallspeech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As seen in [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a#torecognizeallspeech), the [DictationGrammar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.dictationgrammar(v=vs.110).aspx) class has a basic library of common words.

To capture more than one word at once I did

```
 sre.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
```

So my code is now this:

```
    public static SpeechRecognitionEngine sre;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        sre.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("exit")));
        sre.LoadGrammar(new DictationGrammar());
        sre.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }


    private static void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text == "exit")
        {
            sre.RecognizeAsyncStop();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("You said: " + e.Result.Text);
    }
```